# LinkedIn historical-follow-statistics API for current day does not match current follower count

Tags: linkedin-api

Hitting the Historical Follower Count API documented at
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#historical_followers

URL is:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}/historical-follow-statistics?time-granularity=day&start-timestamp=1501718400000&end-timestamp=1501718400000&format=json
```

Those timestamps are both for today. Response is:

```
[                                    
  "_total" => 1,                     
  "values" => [                      
    [                                
      "organicFollowerCount" => 932, 
      "paidFollowerCount" => 84,     
      "time" => 1501718400000.0,     
      "totalFollowerCount" => 1016,  
    ],                               
  ],                                 
]
```

But the actual current follower count on the Company's page is 1009

Which of these number is correct? The follower count for this company does not fluctuate that much to account for this difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Company Followers count mismatch between num-followers and statistics endpoints.

API Endpoint1: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}/company-statistics? API Endpoint2 : https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}/num-followers?

Here in second api endpoint , you can get accurate followers count. But company statistics endpoint returning more followers count than actual count. dont know why