# Linkedin Api returns Follower count not consistent with data shown on LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api

We've noticed a couple of oddities with the LinkedIn api for follower count recently.

1. The follower count for the current day is consistently higher in the API than on the website; seems to be higher by a different constant for each company that we query. This is exactly this question that some other user noticed, we've seen it on several companies: [LinkedIn historical-follow-statistics API for current day does not match current follower count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494626/linkedin-historical-follow-statistics-api-for-current-day-does-not-match-current)
2. For one company for which we queried historical follower counts, there was a large spike in the numbers from the API that doesn't correspond with what is shown on the website. Here's the spike in the API graphed:

[image]

Seems to me that we should trust the website and not the API, but does anyone know for sure? Does anyone know the cause of the discrepancy and if there's any logic we could apply to make the numbers line up?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the website is as of the last snapshot (eg. it's cached), and the API is the current value.

To get these to line up, don't pull the current day because it isn't finished yet.  The etl pattern is to pull yesterday's data sometime after the day has finished.

Comment: I think there's something deeper wrong with their data here -- the discrepancies show up for historical data pulls (i.e., pulling data for several months in the past), not just the current day's pull. Also, the discrepancy shows up even on days when there was no change in the follower count, which suggests it's not a cache latency issue.